# Css triangle - hairline between surrounding divs on zoom/scale

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make div separations with css triangles. Have a look at:
http://codepen.io/rustytusk/pen/aZdZBK

In the codepen everything looks fine, even on mobile. However, in my real project, there are two fine lines on top/bottom, between the triangle and the surrounding divs. This problem seems to show up only on mobile/scaled sites.

I'm using pretty much the same code on the project as on codepen, but somehow there is a problem.

Thats the code I'm using in my project:

```
background-color: white
width: 0
height: 0
border-style: solid
border-width: 0 0 5vh 100vw
border-color: transparent transparent rgb(50, 50, 50) transparent
margin: 0px
padding: 0px
outline: none
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[Screenshot on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtoJL.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the screenshot, now added

Comment: Subpixel rounding no doubt.

Comment: Yes, but is there a solution?

Comment: Yeah...don't use triangles. The optimal solution is, as I recall, either a skewed element or an SVG. SO has covered this a number of times...I'm sure you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, only on viewing a site on iPad, was able to fix it by adding this to the `<head>`:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
```